# Remove keys from JSON based on a list of private keys

Tags: javascript, json

I have some nested JSON I fetch from my mongodb instance, that I want to return as JSON to the client. However, I want to remove any sensitive keys.

I.e. it might look like this:

```
{ name: "Dom", nested_field: { sensitive_key": 12" } }
```

I want to remove sensitive_key at an arbitrary nesting level. Is there a nice util method somewhere I could use, rather than writing my own?

Comment: A simple recursive function should do it very well. It'll require fewer than half the characters you used to type your question.

Comment: Yeah. I was just checking there wasn't some nice function in underscore I was missing

Comment: Second argument of JSON.stringify could be useful.

Comment: _.omit but you still have to do it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

This Might Help

```
for (var key in json_obj) {
    if (json_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do your stuff with `key'
    }
}
```